# Absolute value in double integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, absolute-value

Would be appreciated if anyone could shed some lights on how to solve the double integral with absolute value in it.

\begin{align}
\int_0^t\:du\int_0^\infty e^{-\mu\left|u-s\right|}Ae^{-\lambda s}\:ds,\:\:\left(\mu\neq \lambda\right).\tag{1}
\end{align}

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $A$ is a constant. You divide the inner integral into the following:

$$
\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-\mu|u-s|}Ae^{-\lambda s}\,ds = \int_{0}^ue^{-\mu(u-s)}Ae^{-\lambda s}\,ds+\int_u^{+\infty}e^{-\mu(s-u)}Ae^{-\lambda u}\,ds
$$
and just integrate. It seems that, in addition to your condition on $\mu$ and $\lambda$, (the real part of) $\mu+\lambda$ must be positive for the integral to converge.

Comment: Thanks Mickep, that's the solution indeed!

Answer (score 0):

I think the Inner Integral should be:

$$ \int_0^\infty e^{-\mu\vert u-s \vert} Ae^{-\lambda s} ds = \int_0^u e^{-\mu( u-s)} A e^{-\lambda s} ds + \int_u^\infty e^{-\mu(s-u)} A e^{-\lambda s} ds $$

Note the $ s $ in the second Integral as opposed to the $ u $.  Apologies if I'm wrong but I think it's correct?